# How to use prop data as API input in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a button 'TranslationButton' which fires off the 'text' Prop to the API, and should return a Translation of it. I can see in VueTools that the text is picked up by 'TranslationButton's' text prop, but when I attempt to feed it into the API it tells me:

```
Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "ReferenceError: props is not defined"
```

Full TranslationButton.vue Component below + how I call it in MainComponent.vue

```
    <template>
  <b-button type="is-text" @click="translateMessage()">Übersetzen</b-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TranslationButton",

  props: {
    text: '',
  },

  methods: {
    async translateMessage(data = {}) {
      const url = "https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate";
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          auth_key: "",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          target_lang: "EN-GB",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(props.text),
      });
      return response.json();
    },

  },
};
</script>
```

MainComponent.vue

```
<translation-button :text="props.row.text" />
```

Comment: `body: JSON.stringify(this.text)` & `:text="text"`

Comment: @Radeanu Thanks for the answer, however, it becomes undefined when I try to access it as that 'Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'text')"

Comment: That's because `text` parent component may not provided value for text, you ca set some default value like: `props: { text: { type: String, default: 'default text' } }`.

Comment: In template `props` value are accessible without `props` keyword